# Understanding the gibberish errors when compiling LLVM from source

Tags: gcc, llvm, centos7

Here are the things I did,

1. Compiled and installed gcc-9.2.
2. Compiled and installed GNU binutils-2.32
3. Compiled and installed GNU Make-4.2
4. I downloaded the source code for LLVM, Clang, LLD, libcxx, libcxxabi, lldb, polly, openmp and compiler-rt from the LLVM site (for version 8.0.1).
5. I proceeded to compile LLVM along with the above projects.

During compilation I get some gibberish errors. I reproduce a part of the output below:

```
In file included from /data/stars/user/uujjwal/collection-stars/gcc-9.2/include/c++/9.2.0/iomanip:43,
                 from /tmp/llvm/llvm/utils/PerfectShuffle/PerfectShuffle.cpp:19:
/usr/bin/locale:112:4: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:12: error: stray ‘\30’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:20: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:24: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:28: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:37: error: stray ‘\27’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:38: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:45: error: stray ‘\27’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:52: error: stray ‘\32’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:68: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:84: error: stray ‘\315’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:88: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:92: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:100: error: stray ‘\220’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:101: error: stray ‘\27’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:102: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:108: error: stray ‘\220’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:109: error: stray ‘\27’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:117: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:132: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:140: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:148: error: stray ‘\340’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:152: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:156: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:165: error: stray ‘\34’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:166: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:173: error: stray ‘\34’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:180: error: stray ‘\362’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:196: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:216: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:220: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:228: error: stray ‘\364’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:230: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:236: error: stray ‘\364’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:260: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:276: error: stray ‘\7’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:280: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:284: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:294: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:308: error: stray ‘\331’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:309: error: stray ‘\25’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:340: error: stray ‘\247’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:344: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:348: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:356: error: stray ‘\334’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:358: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:364: error: stray ‘\334’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:373: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:388: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:408: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:412: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:420: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:422: error: stray ‘@’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:428: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:436: error: stray ‘\354’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:437: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:452: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:468: error: stray ‘\362’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:472: error: stray ‘\16’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:476: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:486: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:500: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:516: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:532: error: stray ‘\346’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:536: error: stray ‘\17’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:540: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:548: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:550: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:556: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:564: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:580: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:596: error: stray ‘\242’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:600: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:604: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:612: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:614: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:620: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:628: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:644: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:660: error: stray ‘\31’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:664: error: stray ‘\6’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:668: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:676: error: stray ‘\30’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:678: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:684: error: stray ‘\30’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:692: error: stray ‘\340’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:693: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:700: error: stray ‘\7’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:708: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:716: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:724: error: stray ‘\333’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:728: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:732: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:740: error: stray ‘\370’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:742: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:748: error: stray ‘\370’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:756: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:772: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:780: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:788: error: stray ‘\322’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:792: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:796: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:806: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:821: error: stray ‘\2’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:836: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:844: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:852: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:856: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:860: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:868: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:870: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:876: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:885: error: stray ‘\34’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:916: error: stray ‘\275’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:920: error: stray ‘\10’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:924: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:932: error: stray ‘\320’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:933: error: stray ‘\216’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:934: error: stray ‘`’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:940: error: stray ‘\304’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:941: error: stray ‘\216’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:964: error: stray ‘\20’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:984: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1004: error: stray ‘\304’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1005: error: stray ‘\216’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1012: error: stray ‘\24’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1028: error: stray ‘\4’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1044: error: stray ‘\17’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1048: error: stray ‘\3’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1068: error: stray ‘\330’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1069: error: stray ‘\216’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1076: error: stray ‘\376’ in program
/usr/bin/locale:112:1092: error: stray ‘\1’ in program

    In file included from /data/stars/user/uujjwal/collection-stars/gcc-9.2/include/c++/9.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /tmp/llvm/llvm/utils/PerfectShuffle/PerfectShuffle.cpp:19:
    /usr/bin/locale:4:109: error: ‘t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘tm’?
        4 |            pp`
                                             xp`
                                                                   �p`                    �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`                   �p`        D            q`                  q`                   q`                   q`                    q`                    (q`        !           0q`        "           8q`        #           @q`        $           Hq`        %           Pq`        &           Xq`        '           `q`        (           hq`        )           pq`        *           xq`        +           �q`        ,           �q`        -           �q`        J           �q`        .           �q`        /           �q`        G           �q`        0           �q`        1           �q`        2           �q`        3           �q`        4           �q`        5           �q`        6           �q`        7           �q`        8           �q`        9            r`        :          r`        ;           r`        <           r`        =            r`        >           (r`        ?           0r`        @           8r`        A           @r`        B           H�H��X  H��t��  H��              �5rX  �%tX  @ �%rX  h    ������%jX  h   ������%bX  h   ������%ZX  h   ������%RX  h   ������%JX  h   ������%BX  h   ������%:X  h   �p����%2X     �`����%*X  h    �P����%"X  h
          |                                                                                                             ^
          |                                                                                                             tm
    In file included from /data/stars/user/uujjwal/collection-stars/gcc-9.2/include/c++/9.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /tmp/llvm/llvm/utils/PerfectShuffle/PerfectShuffle.cpp:19:
    /usr/bin/locale:5:721: error: ‘libc’ does not name a type
        5 |    �@����%X  h
                              �0����%X  h
                                             � ����%
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^
    In file included from /data/stars/user/uujjwal/collection-stars/gcc-9.2/include/c++/9.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /tmp/llvm/llvm/utils/PerfectShuffle/PerfectShuffle.cpp:19:
    /usr/bin/locale:12:234: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
       12 |    []A\A]�����D  D�j  E����  1��{~C�     �;��w���H��tH�5�i  H�������H�5�i  �;   �������C��9�ŋ;��<���H��tH�5`i  H�������D� �i  E���X���H�5Ai  �"   �7����B���f��?������ si  H�Ņ��(  H�������E �������L@ ��<E�1�����������D  �?�����H��H���E  H�������A�ċi  ����   A���*  A�D$�A�����H�\f��E ��L@ <��AD�1�H���s���H9�u���������<E�H���L@ 1�[]A\A]�H����     �?����H�ŋ�h  ��u�����     H�[]A\A]�D  H���L@ 1�� �������@ H���L@ 1�������7��� H���L@ 1����������� H�1���L@ ��������� H�1���L@ ���������� H���L@ 1����������� E1������E��D  u
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
    In file included from /data/stars/user/uujjwal/collection-stars/gcc-9.2/include/c++/9.2.0/iomanip:43,
                     from /tmp/llvm/llvm/utils/PerfectShuffle/PerfectShuffle.cpp:19:
    /usr/bin/locale:16:279: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ^
    /usr/bin/locale:16:282: error: ‘H’ does not name a type
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ^
    /usr/bin/locale:16:316: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^
    /usr/bin/locale:16:319: error: ‘u4’ does not name a type
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ^
    /usr/bin/locale:16:355: error: ‘H’ does not name a type
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^
    /usr/bin/locale:16:398: error: ‘M’ does not name a type
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ^
    /usr/bin/locale:16:412: error: ‘u’ does not name a type
       16 | ��   I�WH����u  fD  H��H�����   �DV t�� �SH��H�0�f�     H���H���DF u���tr�CH�K��u�-@ H�����tH���DV t�<
          |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^
    /usr/bin/locale:19:70: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
       19 |    H�������H��t�A�$�����L������L������� ƅ����
          |                                                                      ^
    /usr/bin/locale:19:74: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
       19 |    H�������H��t�A�$�����L������L������� ƅ����
          |                                                                          ^
    make[2]: *** [utils/PerfectShuffle/CMakeFiles/llvm-PerfectShuffle.dir/build.make:63: utils/PerfectShuffle/CMakeFiles/llvm-PerfectShuffle.dir/PerfectShuffle.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:20749: utils/PerfectShuffle/CMakeFiles/llvm-PerfectShuffle.dir/all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The output of `locale` is as below:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I am unable to understand exactly, why I am getting this sort of error. I have searched hard, but cannot find absolutely anything on it. To the best of my knowledge, this kind of problem comes owing to gibberish symbols in a code. Considering that it is a stable release of LLVM, I hope that is not the case. How can I fix this?

Comment: That looks like your preprocessor is including `/usr/bin/locale` instead of the C++ `<locale>` header, which suggests a very badly broken setup.

Comment: Aren't there binary packages of most of all these programs available for your OS? You tagged this Linux, but I don't see a particular distribution mentioned...

Comment: @Shawn I would prefer to compile from source.

Why is the preprocessor including /usr/bin/locale ? Does it convey something about the LLVM source code or my setup ? Can you direct me to some ideas about how I can debug the setup ? For your information, I do not have root permissions on the server I am operating.

Comment: @Shawn It is CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core). I have updated the tags.

Comment: You could check the ouput of `echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only` (in the environment that you try to compile LLVM in; replace `gcc` by path to the actual compiler used if necessary) It should not contain anything like `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @uneven_mark I did that and it does contain /usr/bin. What does it mean and how did it happen ? Is it due to hardcoding of paths somehow when I compiled gcc-9.2 using gcc 4.8.5 ( the one in /usr/bin ) ? How to correct it ?

Comment: @uj14 Is it `/usr/bin` exactly or a subpath thereof? In any case the problem then probably is that you misconfigured the build of gcc. Without the exact steps you took building and installing it, it is hard to say anything more

Comment: @uneven_mark I cleaned by bashrc with several environment variables which I no longer use ( corresponding to earlier versions of many programs). Then /usr/bin no longer appeared and the compilation happened perfectly. Without your help I would never have found the source of the problem and so thanks a ton.

Comment: @uj14 - You might be interested in [GitHub | Build-LLVM](https://github.com/noloader/build-llvm). I used to use it to build LLVM from sources on several platforms. It is a little old so you may need to tweak some variables, like version numbers. It also skips LLDB since I've never been able to get it to build a sign properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error.
Turns out an export typo in my ~/.zshrc was the cause

```
export CPATH=<some_stuff>:$PATH // <---- TYPO
```

Comment: CPATH as a typo of PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the right locale file which is a C source located in `/usr/inlcude/c++/7`, in your case, you may wrongly include the locale executable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).